# Fit wide correlation table on page using siunitx

Tags: tables, tabularx, siunitx

I'm trying to fit a very wide table on one page. Landscape does not do the trick and latex is cutting off half of my columns. Also...I'm having trouble to define the first S-Column (Cases) separately from the other 22 columns to specify, that decimals do not need to be displayed in that column.

```
\documentclass[10pt,ngerman,english]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs,setspace,caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{float}



\pagestyle{empty}

\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator*{spaced}{\\[2ex]}
\captionsetup[table]{textfont=it,format=plain,justification=justified,
  singlelinecheck=false,labelsep=spaced,skip=0pt}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=period,labelfont=it,justification=justified,
  singlelinecheck=false,font=doublespacing}
  
\begin{document}

\sisetup{detect-mode,
        tight-spacing           = true,
        group-digits            = false,
        input-signs             = + -,
        input-open-uncertainty  = ,
        input-close-uncertainty = ,
        round-mode              = places,
        table-number-alignment  = center,
        round-precision         = 2,
        add-integer-zero        = true}
        

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} 
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l*{23}{S[table-format=3.2,
                        table-space-text-post={***}]}}
  \hline
&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Cases}& 
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{M}}&
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{SD}}&
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)} & 
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)} & 
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)} &
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)} & 
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)} & 
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)} & 
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{(7)} & 
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{(8)} & 
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{(9)} & 
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{(10)} & 
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{(11)} & 
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{(12)} & 
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{(13)} & 
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{(14)} & 
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{(15)} & 
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{(16)} & 
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{(17)} & 
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{(18)} & 
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{(19)} & 
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{(20)} \\ 
  \hline
  D & 856 & .5 &.5 \\ 
  A& 856 & .5 &.5 &.29***  \\ 
  I& 856 & .5 &.5 &  .17*** &.22*** \\ 
  C & 856 & .5 &.5&  .03     &  .02     &  .12***    \\ 
  O & 856 & .5 &.5&  .10**   &  .20*** &  .13***  &  .15***  \\ 
  A & 856 & .5 &.5 & -.03     &  .00     &  .09**   &  .17*** &  .24*** \\ 
  C & 856 & .5 &.5 & -.08*    & -.05     & -.10**   & -.24*** & -.06     & -.09*    & -.51*** & -.49*** & -.54*** & -.35*** & -.37*** & -.32*** & -.47*** & -.46*** & -.42*** & -.42*** & -.45*** & -.47*** & -.10**   &  .01 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}        
        
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Regarding the second part of your question: `\begin{tabular}{l S[table-format=3]   *{2}{S[table-format=1.2]}  *{20}{S[table-format=-1.2,table-space-text-post={***}]}}` should work. (The table will howeverr still be wider than the available space.)

Comment: Also, you can remove `\multicolumn{1}{c}` (e.g., {1)}  instead of `\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}`.)  in the column headers. Contents in a set of `{}` insid an `S` type column are horizontally centered by default.Apart from that, I really doubt you will be able to fit that many columns onto a single page while still keeping an a least somewhat readable font size. Probably, you could split up your table into tso parts?